# Shorthand to check if nullable integer is not null and is not specific value in C#

Tags: c#

As the question title, do you know any shorthand to check if nullable integer is not null and is not specific value in C#?

```
int? action = null;
var actionText = action != null && action != 0 ? action.ToString() : "-";
```

Comment: `var actionText = (action ?? 0) != 0 ? action.ToString() : "-";` ?

Comment: `var actionText = action == 0 ? "-" : action?.ToString() ?? "-";` ?

Comment: `action is not null and not 0` - try pattern matching

Comment: what's the purpose here? Your code does its work and is pretty easy to understand. Why change it?

Comment: If `action` will always be positive, then `var actionText = action > 0 ? action.ToString() : "-";` is shorter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching) is the shortest way.

```
var actionText = action is null or 0 ? "-" : action.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [null-coalescing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) `??` to assign the value you want to check if the nullable `int` is actually null and then verify if the result is different from that value

```
int? action = null;
var actionText = (action ?? 0) != 0 ? action.ToString() : "-";
```

In any case you would only skip the `action != null` check, not really a shorthand; another option (probably overkill in this case but suggesting this out of clean code sake) would be to create a dedicated method for this, which could also improve readability of your code, something like

```
int? action = null;
var actionText = GetActionTextOrDefault(action);
.
.
.
public string GetActionTextOrDefault(int? action) {
    return (action ?? 0) != 0 ? action.ToString() : "-";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using netCore you can use :

```
        string actionText = action?.ToString() ?? "custom text";
```

Comment: This doesn't account for `0`, as per the OP's requirements.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay agreed, i guess you could do string actionText = (action ?? 0) != 0 ? action?.ToString() : "-"; But then it's not shorten that much